# Publishing Crystal Reports to ColdFusion Pages

Tags: coldfusion, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I am trying to publish some reports created in Crystal Reports 2008 to the web using ColdFusion. I have read that you just need to use cfreport like this . I have tested this many different ways and all I keep getting is a blank page.

Is it possible to do this? If not how do I publish Crystal Reports to the web? Do we need to have Crystal Reports Server?

Any help would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That wont work, its for really old versions of Crystal way before 2008.

You need to have the appropriate Crystal Enterprise on the server and call their API's to run the reports to PDF etc.

I've done it before but 6 years ago and im sure its all different now.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So the report is still created the same way you just use the API to call the report? Any idea exactly what version of crystal is required?

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with cfreport and crystal for over 10 years and here's what I can offer, hope something might help:

It is possible to print Crystal Reports through ColdFusion a few different ways.  First, you have to understand that ColdFusion Report Builder was created to get rid of some of the headaches associated with Crystal Reports.

1) If you can downgrade your report (File > Save as) A crystal 7 or 8 or maybe 9 version of an rpt file there is a chance it might work directly from cfreport.

2) If that doesn't work you'll have to use a crystal web component to run the report to a pdf and link to it. There's enough Java and .NET examples out there and you can use the Java call directly in cf9, or wrap it in a javaloader cfc call.

3) Call the report through crystal server - If you already have a web based crystal reports server you can attempt to access the report you want through it.  I'd suggest this route first.  There's a web viewer built into the crystal server which you may be able to re-purpose.  I got it working once but it's been too long.

4) You can access the crystal reports developer tools and simply make a call through cfobject for what you need to run the report (aka print) to a PDF and then just use the report.  I'd probably look down this route first because I'm most familiar with it and it might be the least amount of work..

Hope that helps!
J